# Dynamically set the parameter (value_if_true) of an IF formula

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, vba, excel-formula

I am working with large Excel stocks data. I have the data in a format like this,

[image]

What I need to do is, I need to set that stock ticker name in front of the cell which loss is less than -10%.

I can try with the simple =IF(B2<-0.1, "AAL", "") formula, but this will work until the next stock starts, I mean in AADI also it will print "AAL", that's the problem. I need to print the right ticker if this condition is true. If it's AAPL, the ticker AAPL should print in front of the loss cell. So, How can I do that?

Don't know how to complete this while I am having millions of data points. I should know a good solution using Python, VB, or Excel formulas.

Comment: You could use this, `=max(--not(isnumber($b$1:$b2))*row($B$2:$b2))` this will give you the row of non numeric titles above the current row, if you drag it down from row 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here is a simple proposition using [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for num_row in range(1, ws.max_row+1):
    cellB = ws.cell(row=num_row, column=2)

    if isinstance(cellB.value, str):
        ticker_name = cellB.value
    else:
        try:
            cellC = ws.cell(row=num_row, column=3)
            if cellC.value < 0.1:
                ws.cell(row=num_row, column=4).value = ticker_name
        except TypeError:
            pass
        
wb.save("file.xlsx")
```

*NB: Make sure to keep always a backup/copy of your original Excel file before running any kind of python/openpyxl's script.*

##### # Output :

[image]